# function that returns a value stored as a variable in an RData file (without global vars)

Tags: r

I want to get a specific variable value from a stored RData file. Often times in R sample code, the data set is loaded involving global variables.

I want to avoid any global variables and instead write a function that returns the value of a variable stored in an RData file. (This makes is also more explicit which variable is needed.)

How can I program a function returns a value stored as a variable in an RData file (without using any global variables).

(My try ist the function `getVariableFromRData`below, but it is a bit cumbersome and perhaps not correct.)

```
xx <- pi # to ensure there is some data
save(list = ls(all = TRUE), file= "all.RData")
rm(xx)

getVariableFromRData <- function(dataName, varName) {
    e <- new.env()
    load(dataName, envir=e)

    if(varName %in% ls(e)) {
        resultVar <- e[[varName]]
        return(resultVar)
    } else {
        stop (paste0("!! Error: varname (", varName,
                      ") not found in RData (", dataName, ")!"))
    }
}


yy <- getVariableFromRData("all.RData", "xx")
```

Comment: Your approach seems fine to me although using `get` in place of checking if varName is in the output of `ls` would be cleaner and you wouldn't have to create the error yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your solution looks decent.  Compare w/a function I wrote (based on some old SO question) to modify a `.Rdata` file:

```
resave<- function (..., list = character(), file) 
{
    previous <- load(file)
    var.names <- c(list, as.character(substitute(list(...)))[-1L])
    for (var in var.names) assign(var, get(var, envir = parent.frame()))
    save(list = unique(c(previous, var.names)), file = file)
}
```

So strictly speaking you don't need a new environment: you can just query the output of `load` to see if the desired variable name is there.